# Finding pointer arguments with GnuCParser?

Tags: python, gcc, pycparser

I'm trying to parse this fragment of C code:

```
void foo(const int *bar, int * const baz);
```

using `GnuCParser`, part of [pycparserext](https://github.com/inducer/pycparserext).

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21872138/28169) I expected to see some `PtrDecl`s, but here's what I get from `ast.show()` on the resulting parse tree:

```
FileAST:
  Decl: foo, [], [], []
    FuncDecl:
      ParamList:
        Decl: bar, ['const'], [], []
          TypeDeclExt: bar, ['const']
            IdentifierType: ['int']
        Decl: baz, [], [], []
          TypeDeclExt: baz, []
            IdentifierType: ['int']
      TypeDecl: foo, []
        IdentifierType: ['void']
```

Notice how `baz`, a "const pointer to `int`", doesn't have a trace of `const` (or "pointeryness") in the data printed by `ast.show()`. Is this difference because of `GnuCParser`?

How do I figure out the type of `baz` from the AST? My actual C code needs the GNU parser. I'm using pycparserext version 2016.1.

*UPDATE*: I've created a [pycparserext issue on GitHub](https://github.com/inducer/pycparserext/issues/21).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's the issue with pycparserext here, but if I run it through the vanilla [pycparser](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser) I get:

```
FileAST: 
  Decl: foo, [], [], []
    FuncDecl: 
      ParamList: 
        Decl: bar, ['const'], [], []
          PtrDecl: []
            TypeDecl: bar, ['const']
              IdentifierType: ['int']
        Decl: baz, [], [], []
          PtrDecl: ['const']
            TypeDecl: baz, []
              IdentifierType: ['int']
      TypeDecl: foo, []
        IdentifierType: ['void']
```

Which looks entirely reasonable for this input.

Comment: Right, that's along the lines of what I was expecting. It seems it's something with GnuCParser, then. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

This was due to a bug in pycparserext, it has been fixed now by the maintainer and the issue mentioned in the question has been closed. The fix is in release 2016.2.

The output is now:

```
>>> from pycparserext.ext_c_parser import GnuCParser
>>> p=GnuCParser()
>>> ast=p.parse("void foo(const int *bar, int * const baz);")
>>> ast.show()
FileAST:
  Decl: foo, [], [], []
    FuncDecl:
      ParamList:
        Decl: bar, ['const'], [], []
          PtrDecl: []
            TypeDecl: bar, ['const']
              IdentifierType: ['int']
        Decl: baz, [], [], []
          PtrDecl: ['const']
            TypeDecl: baz, []
              IdentifierType: ['int']
      TypeDecl: foo, []
        IdentifierType: ['void']
```

Clearly this contains more `Ptr` nodes, which is a very good sign. The pycparserext code has also had a test added to catch this in the future.

Very impressive. :)